# ui-router docs built in bootstrap... how to re-create?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I noticed that ui-router appears to be using the bootstrap docs to publish API documentation.  Where can I find information on how I can publish documentation for my project using this approach?

Here is the site -

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: They use https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs, the page is hosted on github pages. Both are free to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-router uses [grunt-ngdocs](https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs) module. You can host generated docs on free [github pages](https://pages.github.com/).